# iPhone - Screenshot of multiple OpenGL (CAEaglelayer) views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, xcode4.2, eaglview

I am working on paint app taking reference from GLPaint app. In this app there are two canvas views, one view is moving from left to right (animating) and other view is used as background view (as shown in figure).

[image]

I am using CAEAGLLayer for filling colors in both views (using subclassing technique). It is working as expected. Now I have to take screenshot of the complete view (outlines and both OpenGL views), but I am getting screenshot of only one view (either moving view or background view).  Code related to screenshot is associated with both views but at a time only one view's content is saved.

Code snippet for screenshot as follows.

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot:(UIView*)eaglview{

GLint backingWidth, backingHeight;

// Bind the color renderbuffer used to render the OpenGL ES view
// If your application only creates a single color renderbuffer which is already bound at this point, 
// this call is redundant, but it is needed if you're dealing with multiple renderbuffers.
// Note, replace "_colorRenderbuffer" with the actual name of the renderbuffer object defined in your class.

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

// Get the size of the backing CAEAGLLayer
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);
NSInteger x = 0, y = 0, width = backingWidth, height = backingHeight;
NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
GLubyte *data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength * sizeof(GLubyte));
// Read pixel data from the framebuffer
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

// Create a CGImage with the pixel data
// If your OpenGL ES content is opaque, use kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast to ignore the alpha channel
// otherwise, use kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast

CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, height, 8, 32, width * 4, colorspace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast,
                                ref, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
// OpenGL ES measures data in PIXELS
// Create a graphics context with the target size measured in POINTS

NSInteger widthInPoints, heightInPoints;
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
    // On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into consideration
    // Set the scale parameter to your OpenGL ES view's contentScaleFactor
    // so that you get a high-resolution snapshot when its value is greater than 1.0
    CGFloat scale = eaglview.contentScaleFactor;
    widthInPoints = width / scale;
    heightInPoints = height / scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints), NO, scale);
}
else {
    // On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
    widthInPoints = width;
    heightInPoints = height;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(widthInPoints, heightInPoints));
}
CGContextRef cgcontext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// UIKit coordinate system is upside down to GL/Quartz coordinate system
// Flip the CGImage by rendering it to the flipped bitmap context
// The size of the destination area is measured in POINTS
CGContextSetBlendMode(cgcontext, kCGBlendModeCopy);
CGContextDrawImage(cgcontext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, widthInPoints, heightInPoints), iref);

// Retrieve the UIImage from the current context
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  // Clean up
free(data);
CFRelease(ref);
CFRelease(colorspace);
CGImageRelease(iref);

 return image; 
}
```

Is there any way to combine content of both CAEaglelayer views?

Please help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am having the same requirement what you have implemented. where static background  image and moving image on that (in my case drawing) but some how I am not able to achieve that.I have also ask my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131213/drawing-with-with-blur-effect-on-image-using-opengl Will you please look into it. You might be able to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create screenshots of each view by separate and then combine them as follows:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvasSize);

[openGLImage1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, canvasSize.width, canvasSize.height)];
[openGLImage2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, canvasSize.width, canvasSize.height)];

UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

you should use appropriate canvasSize and frame to draw each generated UIImage, it is just a sample of how you could do it

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15777434/373944) for a much better way of doing this. It basically allows you to capture a larger view that contains all of your OpenGL (and other) views into one, fully composed screenshot that's identical to what you see on the screen.