# How to achieve better performance in converting UIView to CVPixelBuffer?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, calayer, metal, cvpixelbuffer

I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve a better performance in converting the `UIView` into `CVPixelBuffer`.

My app converts a sequence of `UIView`s first into `UIImage`s and then into `CVPixelBuffer`s as shown below. In the end, I record all these images/frames into an `AVAssetWriterInput` and save the result as a movie file.

Thank you in advance!

Best, Aibek

```swift
func viewToImage(view: UIView) -> CGImage {
  let rect: CGRect = container.frame

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, true, 1)

  let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
  view.layer.render(in: context)
  let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

  return img!.cgImage
}
```

```swift
func imageToBuffer(image: CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
  let frameSize = CGSize(width: image.width, height: image.height)

  var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
  let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(frameSize.width), Int(frameSize.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, nil, &pixelBuffer)

  if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
    return nil
  }

  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
  let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)
  let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
  let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
  let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(frameSize.width), height: Int(frameSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

  context?.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.width, height: image.height))

  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

  return pixelBuffer
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the UIViews into MTLTextures and recording them into a video file using the Recorder provided by [Mayo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13680955/%EB%A7%88%EC%9A%94mayo) didn't increase the performance actually.

However, the recorder is able to write MTLTextures in real-time. That meant for me that I can re-write all the animations using Metal and use the recorder.

Comment: Long time no see. What do you mean that `re-write all the animations`?

Comment: True, it's been a while! I mean, I have to adopt all the processing stuff with Metal. Currently, I use `UIView`s to draw animated stuff into the `CALayer`. This differs from how Metal works. So, I need to re-write all the processing code to create primitives of all my elements and write shaders functions to properly display those primitives.

Comment: Good for you anyway that you figure out what you have to do :)

Comment: Good luck for all your codes

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to see this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61862728/13680955

In short, this sample converts UIView to MTLTexture in 12ms.

Sure you can use CVPixelBuffer directly, but I used MTLTexture to make video and no issue  was on it.

If you are struggling with the performance, too slow or weird to use, try to  do this.

With MTLTexture

```
import AVFoundation
import MetalKit

class VideoRecorder {
    let assetWriter: AVAssetWriter
    let assetWriterVideoInput: AVAssetWriterInput
    let assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter: AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
    var recordingStartTime = TimeInterval(0)
    var recordingElapsedTime = TimeInterval(0)
    let url: URL = {
        let fileName = "exported_video.mp4"
        return FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }()

    init(outputSize: CGSize) throws {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
        }
        let fileType: AVFileType = .mov
        assetWriter = try AVAssetWriter(outputURL: url, fileType: fileType)
        let mediaType: AVMediaType = .video
        let outputSettings: [String: Any] = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoWidthKey: outputSize.width,
            AVVideoHeightKey: outputSize.height
        ]
        assetWriterVideoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: mediaType, outputSettings: outputSettings)
        assetWriterVideoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = false
        let sourcePixelBufferAttributes: [String: Any] = [
            kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
            kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: outputSize.width,
            kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: outputSize.height
        ]
        assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(
            assetWriterInput: assetWriterVideoInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributes)
        assetWriter.add(assetWriterVideoInput)
    }

    private static func currentTimestampString() -> String {
        let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

    public func start() {
        print("videoRecorder.start")
        assetWriter.startWriting()
        assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: .zero)
        recordingStartTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
    }

    public func cancel() {
        #if DEBUG
        print("videoRecorder.cancel")
        #endif

        assetWriterVideoInput.markAsFinished()
        assetWriter.cancelWriting()
    }

    public func finish(_ callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("videoRecorder.finish")
        assetWriterVideoInput.markAsFinished()
        assetWriter.finishWriting {
            self.recordingElapsedTime = CACurrentMediaTime() - self.recordingStartTime
            print("videoRecorder.finish elapsedTime: \(self.recordingElapsedTime)")
            callback()
        }
    }

    private var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?

    public func writeFrame(texture: MTLTexture, at presentationTime: CMTime) {
        print("videoRecorder.writeFrame: \(presentationTime)")
        if pixelBuffer == nil {
            guard let pixelBufferPool = assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter.pixelBufferPool else {
                print("Pixel buffer asset writer input did not have a pixel buffer pool available;")
                print("cannot retrieve frame")
                return
            }

            var maybePixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
            let status  = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(nil, pixelBufferPool, &maybePixelBuffer)
            if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
                print("Could not get pixel buffer from asset writer input; dropping frame...")
                return
            }
            pixelBuffer = maybePixelBuffer
            print("videoRecorder.writeFrame: pixelBuffer was created: \(String(describing: pixelBuffer))")
        }

        guard let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer else {
            print("videoRecorder.writeFrame: NO pixelBuffer")
            return
        }

        writeFrame(texture: texture, at: presentationTime, with: pixelBuffer)
    }

    private func writeFrame(texture: MTLTexture, at presentationTime: CMTime, with pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        while !assetWriterVideoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            //
            print("NOT ready for more media data at: \(presentationTime)")
        }
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])
        let pixelBufferBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)!

        // Use the bytes per row value from the pixel buffer since its stride may be rounded up to be 16-byte aligned
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)
        let region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height)

        texture.getBytes(pixelBufferBytes, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)

        assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdapter.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, [])
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @마요mayo! Thanks for replying to this.

I like your second suggestion more about recording the `MTLTexture` into a video file. However, will the converting `UIView`s to `MTLTexture`s and recording (first suggestion) slow down the recording process?

I'm also worried about re-writing the rendering stuff with Metal. Do you think it is worth that? How much performance increase can I expect from Metal?

Best, Aibek

Comment: In simulator 13pro and real device 13pro, real time playing video, it didn't drop frame. Does your method performs very bad?

Comment: Rendering of UIViews with the approach above with video output 1080p @ 60fps and video duration of 2:30 takes around ~20-25 minutes.

Comment: oh.. then you can use this method. 1080p, 3:00, iPhone 13pro, it takes 3:00. Sure, I didn't used  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61862728/13680955 this. But, with Metal, it doesn't take that long.

Comment: Hi Mayo! Just wanted to share that I've checked your approach. From my perspective, I didn't see any performance increase from converting the UIView to MTLTexture and recording it with your recorder. But I started researching how Metal works in hope that I can re-create all the animations in Metal and use Metal + Recorder to export videos. So far I could make some basic animations and tried to record textures as video frames. Looks like it performs fast enough, considering I write frames in realtime. Thanks for helping me out!