# Metal API, GetBytes Validation rowBytes(1600) must be >= (4680)

Tags: ios, swift, metal

Metal experts!

I'm struggling with the following error:

```swift
failed assertion `GetBytes Validation rowBytes(1600) must be >= (4680)
```

at

```swift
texture.getBytes(pixelBufferBytes, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
```

when I try to record the `MTLTexture` as a video frame using `AVFoundation`. Therefore I'm converting the `MTLTexture` into the `CVPixelBuffer` using the following [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74471573/10309700) (see `VideoRecorder.writeFrame`).

Here is the place where I pass the texture into the recorder:

```swift
extension MetalRenderer: MTKViewDelegate {
  func mtkView(_: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange _: CGSize) {}

  func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable, let descriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else {
      return
    }

    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor)!

    let deltaTime = 1 / Float(view.preferredFramesPerSecond)
    scene?.render(commandEncoder: commandEncoder, deltaTime: deltaTime)

    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.present(drawable)
    commandBuffer.commit()

    commandBuffer.addCompletedHandler { commandBuffer in
      let texture = drawable.layer.nextDrawable()?.texture
      recorder.writeFrame(forTexture: texture!)
    }
  }
}
```

I suppose, something could be wrong with `addCompletedHandler` or grabbing the texture maybe?

#### Workarounds

*Workaround 1*

> I tried to disable the Metal API Validation in Run Scheme and got a bunch of the following errors, but not sure how relevant they are:

```
2023-01-29 23:03:50.009525+0100 [Client] Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
```

*Workaround 2*

> Also, I tried to set the `metalView.framebufferOnly` to `false`, which didn't help to resolve the crash.

I'd appreciate it if someone could answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the width height values of MTLTexture and CVPixelBuffer?

Comment: The values are:

pixel buffer width: 390
pixel buffer height: 844

texture width: 1170
texture height: 1519

Comment: This makes me think that a mismatch between the sizes is causing the error, correct? They need to be equal, I suppose. Is there any way to control texture size? 

Comment: when creating the buffer use texture.width and texture.height for width and height

Comment: and what about setting the texture's size? for example, if we want to render the video in 780p resolution?

Comment: btw. using the texture's size for recording did the trick. thank you very much, udi

Comment: Looks like I could achieve the changed resolution through `MPSImageLanczosScale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `` failed assertion `GetBytes Validation rowBytes(1600) must be >= (4680) `` says that the number of bytes in the row of the `CVPixelBuffer` obtained from the `MTLTexture` is not enough to hold the entire row of data in the texture.

So matching the `CVPixelBuffer` dimensions with the `MTLTexture` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same sizes of `MTLTexture` and `CVPixelBuffer` solved the issue. Big thanks to [udi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11905533/udi) for fixing this!